# TextEditor sticking to minHeight inSwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to build a view with the newly introduced `TextEditor`. The idea is that I have some content at the top (blue frame), then a `ScrollView` with a `TextEditor` and a variable number of `Text` below it (red frame).

The `TextEditor`(yellow frame) view is supposed to have a minimum height, but should take up all the available space if there aren't to many `Text` views following – which it currently does not do...

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewWithTextEditor: View {
    
    var comments = ["Foo", "Bar", "Buzz"]
    
    var loremIpsum = """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    """
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("Some Content above")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 3.0)
            .padding(.all, 10)

            ScrollView {
                ScrollView {
                    TextEditor(text: .constant(loremIpsum))
                        .frame(minHeight: 200.0)
                }
                .frame(minHeight: 200.0)
                .border(Color.yellow, width: 3.0)
                .cornerRadius(3.0)
                .padding(.all, 10.0)
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach(comments, id: \.self) { comment in
                        Text(comment)
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                    .cornerRadius(3.0)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                }
                
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 200.0)
            .border(Color.red, width: 3)
            .padding(.all, 3)
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollViewWithTextEditor_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollViewWithTextEditor()
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: In ScrollView *available space* is infinity, so it is not clear what do you mean to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, my bad – I actually forgot to add the screenshot... Basically, what I want is the `TextEditor` which is part of its own ScrollView (yellow frame) to take up the available space within its container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
ScrollView {
    // make clear static text in background to define size and
    // have TextEditor in front with same text fit
    Text(loremIpsum).foregroundColor(.clear).padding(8)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .overlay(
        TextEditor(text: .constant(loremIpsum))
    )
}
.frame(minHeight: 200.0)
.border(Color.yellow, width: 3.0)
```

Comment: When the text editor starts with less than a full line of text though, it's center-aligned. I could not figure out how to give it a leading alignment as would be default with a standalone non-overlayed text editor.

Comment: That's an interesting technique. Doesn't quite work like I'd want it to (think I didn't make a good enough job to describe what I desire), but it definitely get's close to that. Will elaborate more on it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the ScrollView to dynamically adjust height of TextEditor:

```
import SwiftUI
// Dynamische Höhe des TextEditor, abhängig von Länge des Textes
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357649/808593

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var textLong: String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    @State private var textShort: String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Long")
            Text(textLong).foregroundColor(.clear).padding(8)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(
                    TextEditor(text: $textLong)
                )
                .frame(minHeight: 20.0)
                .border(Color.yellow, width: 3.0)
            
            Text("Short")
            Text(textShort).foregroundColor(.clear).padding(8)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(
                    TextEditor(text: $textShort)
                )
                .frame(minHeight: 20.0)
                .border(Color.yellow, width: 3.0)
        }
       
    }
    
}
```

[image: Playground Screenshot]