# Controlling size of TextEditor in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanted to have some `TextEditor` in my ForEach and I made this sample code in down! As you can see the code and result of it in Image, `TextEditor` act like a greedy view, and takes all available space! which has so many downsides for me at least!

If I go and limit the hight to a custom value then I would loss the possibility of seeing all strings and lines of strings of TextEditor in itself and I must scroll up or down for seeing other lines, which is not my design!

My goal is that the `TextEditor` takes the space as it needs and if I enter new line of string then it can grow in height or if I remove the lines of strings it can shrinks in height to minimum of 1 line at least!

I wonder how can I do this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var textEditorReferenceType: TextEditorReferenceType = TextEditorReferenceType()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("TextEditorView").bold().padding()
        
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(textEditorReferenceType.arrayOfString.indices, id: \.self, content: { index in
                
                TextEditorView(string: $textEditorReferenceType.arrayOfString[index])

            })
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}


struct TextEditorView: View {
    
    @Binding var string: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TextEditor(text: $string)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .shadow(radius: 1.0)
        
    }
    
}

class TextEditorReferenceType: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var arrayOfString: [String] = ["Hello, World!", "Hello, World!", "Hello, World!"]
    
}
```

### Result of current code:

[image]

### Result of my Goal:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357649/12299030? Also this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621521/12299030.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a `PreferenceKey` and an invisible `Text` overlay to measure the string dimensions and set the `TextEditor`'s frame:

```
struct TextEditorView: View {
    
    @Binding var string: String
    @State var textEditorHeight : CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(string)
                .font(.system(.body))
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .padding(14)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
            
            TextEditor(text: $string)
                .font(.system(.body))
                .frame(height: max(40,textEditorHeight))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                            .shadow(radius: 1.0)
        }.onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { textEditorHeight = $0 }
        
    }
    
}


struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```

Adapted from my other answer here: [Mimicking behavior of iMessage with TextEditor for text entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546370/mimicking-behavior-of-imessage-with-texteditor-for-text-entry)

Comment: thanks, it works nice, I want to know if TextEditor gave this options for us as native?

Comment: No -- that's why we have to use solutions like this.

Comment: Why do you suppose Apple is making SwiftUI so danged screwy? Why can't you just apply "scaledToFit()" and it just works? SwiftUI feels like such a poorly-done API... it is so limited and bad in so many ways that it really hurts my brain. I don't understand why Apple would make something like this... and then make it so crappy...

Comment: It would be a nice addition, but remember, it's a relatively young framework. This probably isn't the right forum for value judgements, though.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for this and I saw jnpdx answered the question and I never copy pasted so fast in my life!

Comment: @jnpdx When the above `ZStack` without a max height for the `textEditor` is used within a VStack with another view, do you know why the `onPreferenceChange`  stops getting called after a few lines of the text editor expanding?

Comment: While this is somewhat clever, it's also incredibly fragile with the spacing and such. It also seems to break when using dynamic font sizing.   More importantly, it's not needed!  Check out the answer I just posted. It leverages `fixedSize` and `layoutPriority` to properly squish it down as wanted.

Comment: As stated above, this is a fragile approach. el3ankaboot's solution below is cleaner. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76279357/2670899

Answer (score 25):

### **iOS 16 - Native SwiftUI**

In iOS 16 it's now natively possible with a regular `textField` by adding `axis: .vertical` and `.lineLimit()`

linelimit defines the number of lines until the textfield extends.
Add a range to start to define a range of lines within the textfield will start and stop to extend.

[image]

WWDC22 Session "What'S new in SwiftUI around 17:10

Comment: This is just for iOS? I'm building a MacOs App and the `axis` property isn't available. I have the latest Xcode so not sure what's happening.

Comment: This does not work for TextEditor, which allows newlines etc

Comment: This question is about `TextEditor`, not `TextField`

Answer (score 9):

Adding `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` and a minimum height solved the issue for me.

Example :

```
TextEditor(text: $myBinding)
           .frame(minHeight: 50)
           .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's simple and works perfectly.

Comment: Yes. I totally agree

Comment: This works when expanding, but doesn't shrink the it when you delete text.

Answer (score 7):

### Pure and Simple SwiftUI Approach *(*...and actually using `TextEditor`, not `TextField`!)*

Contrary to some of the answers here, as others have pointed out, the OP specifically asked about `TextEditor`, not `TextField`.  You need `TextEditor` if you want to support explicitly adding new-lines during text entry, not just wrapping a single line to span many.

The easiest solution for achieving this with `TextEditor` requires two things:

1. Using `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on the `TextEditor` *(to dictate the absolute minimum height)*
2. Having another greedy control with a higher layout priority within the same container *(to smoosh it to that height!)*

Here's an example where I have a `Button` directly underneath an auto-growing `TextEditor`. I'm using `Color.clear` with an infinite frame to make it greedy, then `.layoutPriority(1)` to make it overpower the greediness of the `TextEditor` control.  The `fixedSize` on that `TextEditor` says 'Yo, you can't collapse past my text, brah!!', thus that's as far as it smooshes to.  Without `fixedSize`, it would collapse to a height of zero.

```swift
struct TestApp: App {

    static private let initialText = """
        He: Tell me a joke!

        She: Ok... what do you call two crows sitting on a branch?

        He: I dunno, what?

        She: Attempted murder!
        """

    @State private var text: String = Self.initialText

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                TextEditor(text: $text)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                Button("Test Me") {
                    text = Self.initialText
                }

                Color.clear
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .layoutPriority(1)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

> *Side-note: As mentioned above, `layoutPriority` only affects layout in the current container so make sure the greedy control it's applied to is either a direct sibling of your `TextEditor` (i.e. they have the same/immediate parent) or the `TextEditor` is further down the layout, not above.*
>
> *This also means if you nest the below `VStack` inside another `VStack` with some other controls, the children of that outer `VStack`--including your inner `VStack`--will again be distributed equally within it (unless of course you apply `layoutPriority` to any of those controls too.)*

As mentioned above, I use an explicit greedy spacer control there: `Color.clear` with the frame.  However, technically it isn't needed as you can add a frame directly to the button to achieve the same thing.  You just need to also specify the appropriate `alignment` value to say where you want that button to end up in the frame's resulting greedy area. Here that's `.topLeading` so the button ends up directly underneath the `TextEditor` on the left side. If you don't add the `alignment`, the button would end up in the middle of the greedy area as `.center` is the default alignment.

That said, I personally prefer explicit layouts so the spacer is my choice, but others may prefer the simplicity of not needing a dedicated control just for that.*

```swift
// `alignment: topLeading` in the frame puts the button in the top-left of the 'greedy' area that the frame creates
Button("Test Me") {
    text = Self.initialText
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
.layoutPriority(1)
```

And here are examples of the results...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: as seen in the screenshots unfortunately the Color.clear also adds an empty space that I'm not sure how to remove

Comment: @aehlke, I believe that's because the color has a default, non-zero min height.  Try explicitly setting that to zero and see if that helps.  Alternately, just move the spacer underneath all other controls you want 'butted up' against the textview.  Basically wherever you would want the expanded area to be.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just, y'know, use a `Form` guys:

```
struct JustUseAForm: View {
    @State var text1: String = "Enter Text Here"
    @State var text2: String = "Enter Text Here"
    @State var text3: String = "Enter Text Here"

    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Group {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer(minLength: 8)
                    Text("Comment 1:")
                    TextEditor(text: $text1)
                        .padding(.all, 1.0)
                    
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer(minLength: 8)
                    Text("Comment 2:")
                    TextEditor(text: $text2)
                        .padding(.all, 1.0)
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer(minLength: 8)
                    Text("Comment 3:")
                    TextEditor(text: $text3)
                        .padding(.all, 1.0)
                }
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.sRGB, red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, opacity: 0.9))
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
                    
    }
}
```

Example:

[image: just use a form bro]

Of course, this means you have to be OK with the default way Forms render, because just like `.sheet` and most other things in SwiftUI, Apple gives us no way to customize the appearance. You either like what they give us, or you figure out a bizarre hack, or you wrap a UIKit implementation.

Fun times.

Maybe in the comments someone can explain for us why `TextEditor` magically works properly within a `Form` but not anywhere else? Or why `scaleToFit()` does not work properly with `TextEditor`? Or why `lineLimit` does not work properly with `TextEditor`? So many questions, so few answers, unless you work at Apple, I guess.

Comment: I didn’t used Form in my code!

Comment: Form doesn't work for me... I still get a greedy TextEditor. Mind sharing whatever is containing your view?

Comment: There are sooooo many issues with `Form` controls (like not being able to use an `HStack` in them on macOS for one!) I'd strongly advise against using them and just do your layout manually.  As for how to solve this, check out the answer I just posted. Keeps the layout dirt-simple.

Comment: doesn't help for views that must be sized to their content afaict