# TextField how to set width to hold certain number of characters

Tags: swiftui, width, textfield

is it possible to set the width of SwiftUI TextField to hold a certain number of characters and display them without cutting them off? This way the width would adjust automatically based on font size.

The
.frame(width/minWidth/maxWidth) is not really useful in this sense unless I would calculate the size of the characters.

Thanks for any ideas.
Libor

Comment: You could adjust the strategy here to change width instead of height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002976/560942

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution and that is
TextField(....)
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)