# SwiftUI TextEditor Divider doesn't change Y position based on text-line count?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a SwiftUI TextEditor with a Divider that adapts its position to stay under the bottom-most line of text inside of a edit-bio section of the app.

Note: I have a frame on my TextEditor so that it doesn't take up the whole-screen

Right now the Divider is static and stays in one place. Is there a built-in way to make the divider stay under the bottom most line of text?

I would think the Spacer would have given me this behavior?

Thank you!

[image]

```
struct EditBio: View {
    @ObservedObject var editProfileVM: EditProfileViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            TextEditor(text: $editProfileVM.bio)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.top, 70)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 50)
                .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
            Divider().frame(height: 1).background(.white)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002976/560942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing exactly what you told it to do. But a background color on your `TextEditor`. You will see that it has a height of 200 + a spacing of 10 from the `VStack`.

I changed your code to make it obvious:

```
struct EditBio: View {
    @State var editProfileVM = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            TextEditor(text: $editProfileVM)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.top, 70)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 50)
                .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.gray)
            Divider().frame(height: 1).background(.red)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

to produce this:

[image]

You can see the `TextEditor` naturally wants to be taller than 200, but that is limiting it. Therefore, the `Spacer()` is not going to cause the `TextEditor` to be any smaller.

The other problem that setting a fixed frame causes will be that your text will end up off screen at some point. I am presuming what you really want is a self sizing `TextEditor` that is no larger than it's contents.

That can be simply done with the following code:

```
struct EditBio: View {
    @State var editProfileVM = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            SelfSizingTextEditor(text: $editProfileVM)
             // Frame removed for the image below.
            // .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                // made the .top padding to be .vertical
                .padding(.vertical, 70)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 50)
                .background(Color.gray)
            Divider().frame(height: 5).background(.red)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct SelfSizingTextEditor: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @State var textEditorSize = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .copySize(to: $textEditorSize)
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .frame(height: textEditorSize.height)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
            .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }

    func copySize(to binding: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        self.readSize { size in
            binding.wrappedValue = size
        }
    }
}
```

producing this view:

[image]