# Limiting height of dynamic TextEditor in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was trying to figure out how to limit texteditor maximum height. I'm trying to modify this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002976/21548222. When adding maximum height, the view expands always. I was trying to use ternary operator for setting maximum height, but unsuccessful. Anybody knows?

```
    struct TextEditorView: View {
    
    @Binding var string: String
    @State var textEditorHeight : CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(string)
                .font(.system(.body))
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .padding(14)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
            
            TextEditor(text: $string)
                .font(.system(.body))
                .frame(height: max(40,textEditorHeight))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                            .shadow(radius: 1.0)
        }.onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { textEditorHeight = $0 }
        
    }
    
}


struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you have an issue with in the question.

Comment: try to restrict textEditorHeight updating in .onPreferenceChange, add if $0 < yourMaxHeight condition

Comment: I tried already. "textEditorHeight >= 100 ? 100 : textEditorHeight"

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using a restriction on the `textEditorHeight` when updating it, such as:

```
struct TextEditorView: View {
    @Binding var string: String
    @State var textEditorHeight: CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(string)
                .font(.system(.body))
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .padding(14)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
            
            TextEditor(text: $string)
                .border(.red) // <--- for testing
                .font(.system(.body))
                .frame(height: max(40,textEditorHeight))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                .shadow(radius: 1.0)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
            textEditorHeight = $0 >= 100 ? 100 : $0 // <-- here
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }

    // -- here CGFloat
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) { 
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```