# SwiftUI TextEditor expands incorrectly in a VStack with maxWidth

Tags: swiftui

I have two `TextEditor`s in a `VStack` in my app. I would like each of them to expand to fit the text they contain, but remain hugging the text. Unfortunately, long text in the first `TextEditor` expands both `TextEditor`s equally. It is as if the total height of the `VStack` they are in is expanded correctly, but the extra height is shared between the two editors.

This only occurs when I use a maxWidth on the VStack. If I fix the width it behaves correctly.

Is there some way to solve this without losing the resize behaviour maxWidth gives?

[image: Initial text locations]

[image: With expanded text]

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        TextEditor(text: Binding($note.details)!)
            .font(.body)

        TextEditor(text: Binding($note.title)!)
            .font(.title)

    }.frame(maxWidth: 450)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357649/12299030?

Comment: It does! I had tried ZStack but that didn't cut it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on both editors.