# SwiftUI Text Editor how can I keep track of the number of lines in the editor

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I have a TextEditor using SwiftUI 3.0 and every time a new line is created I want to increase the editor height by about 16 points . The issue that I have is that my code is not recognizing the new line being formed . The line count stays at 1 and the editor does not expand . I have looked at a few examples but have not gotten it to work . Any suggestions would be great . The code below is the complete code .

```
import SwiftUI

struct CommentTestView: View {
    @State var Posting = ""
    @State var height: CGFloat = 30
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        Text("Placeholder")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 13.5))
                            .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                            .padding(.vertical, 9)
                            .opacity(Posting.isEmpty ? 1 : 0)

                        TextEditor(text: $Posting)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 14))
                            .frame(height: height)
                            .opacity(Posting.isEmpty ? 0.25 : 1)
                            .onChange(of: self.Posting, perform: { value in
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1), {
                                    print("test line number: \( value.numberOfLines())" )
                                    let LineCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(value.numberOfLines())
                                    if value.numberOfLines() == 0 || value.isEmpty {
                                        // initial height
                                        height = 35
                                    } else {
                                        height = 16 * LineCount
                                    }
                                })
                            })
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.5)
                    )
                }
        }
    }


struct CommentTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    var hhh = TimeLineInsertions()
    static var previews: some View {
        CommentTestView()
    }
}

extension String {
    func numberOfLines() -> Int {
        return self.numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: "\n") + 1
    }

    func numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: String) -> Int {
        return self.components(separatedBy:string).count - 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357649/12299030?

Comment: Hi that one does not since they are trying to do something different

Comment: Why is @Asperi s answer (with a clear background text for sizing) not working for you? I would have been going into the same direction. Don't you want to have the Editor growing in reaction to the input text? Or do you need the lines count for something else?

Comment: FYI, your code works for me with Swift 5, ios-15 catalyst 12. The editor space grows, and the line numbers are updated. I guess it is different on older systems/swift versions.

Comment: Yes for some reason it did not work for my needs but I finally have it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work smoothly and I just needed to make a few changes . With the changes below I just track the size of the Text instead of the number of lines and update the TextEditor accordingly . For the number of lines it only worked when I would press enter .

```
struct CommentVTestView: View {
    @State var Posting = ""
    @State var height: CGFloat = 30.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            TextEditor(text: $Posting)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 15))
                .border(Color.gray)
                .padding([.bottom], 5)
                   .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                   .cornerRadius(3)
                .frame(width: 200, height: height)

            

                Text(Posting)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 190)
                    .hidden()
                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 15))
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: self.Posting, perform: { value in
                                if proxy.size.height > height {
                                    height = proxy.size.height + 17.0
                                }
                            })
                        
                    })
            
            
        }
    }
}
```